# What algorithm use to find the intersection area between polygon and circle?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dictionary, geometry, polygon

I have map. On the top of map layer have a polygon A and circle B. They are intersected each others. Any algorithm can calculate the area of intersection C ?[image]

Comment: How general a problem do you need to solve? Is the polygon always simple (non-self-intersecting)? If so, is the polygon always convex? Is the polygon known to intersect the circle at only two points (as shown)?

Comment: @TedHopp, yes the polygon always non-self intersecting. But is non-convex polygon. No, there will be more points intersect when circle move inner polygon.

Comment: To find the area of the intersection, first draw a line between the two points of intersection. Then compute the area of the remainder of the polygon and add the area of the segment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you're willing to take an approximation of the circle (a polygon with a large number of sides...) then there are a bunch of algorithms to compute the result of polygon clipping (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28computer_graphics%29), for a short listing).

A simple implementation pretty boils down to:

1. Determining what set of polygon A's points lie within polygon B, and vice versa
2. Determining the points of intersection for line segments that cross that inside-outside boundary, and
3. Constructing a new polygon from the set of points collected. To calculate the area of that new polygon, you can just decompose it into a collection of triangles and sum their areas.

If you don't feel like going through all of that work, try [JS Clipper](http://sourceforge.net/p/jsclipper/wiki/Home/). It will probably make your life easier.

If you're not willing to make do with an arbitrarily good approximation of your circle, I figure you have to start finding intersections between polygon line segments and the boundary of your circle, then piecewise integrating each section.

Comment: After go through the JS clipper. I don't know where to start to use the script to calculate the area of intersection. Can you briefly give some hints to achieve the result ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without approximations:

1. find intersections between polygon and circle
2. compose border of region of intersection - you will have sequence of line segments and arcs
3. calculate area of the region using Green's formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Area_Calculation - `Integral[border](x*dy-y*dx)`

For every line segment calculating this integral is trivial - it's just `x0*y1-y0*x1`.

For circle arc it's a bit more verbose. Final result is `Cx*(y1-y0) - Cy*(x1-x0) ) + R^2*(t1-t0)`, where `(Cx,Cy)` is center of circle, `(x0,y0)` is start of arc, `(x1,y1)` is end of arc, `t0` is starting angle of arc, `t1` is finishing angle of arc.

Just to make possible for anyone to verify the derivation, here is it:
(for sure, it can be derived from geometry, but I've did it through formulas)

`Integral[arc](x*dy-y*dx)`

`Integral[t=t0..t1]( (Cx+R*cos t)*R*cos t - (Cy+R*sin t)*(-R*sin t) )dt`

`Integral[t=t0..t1]( (Cx+R*cos t)*R*cos t + (Cy+R*sin t)*R*sin t )dt`

`Integral[t=t0..t1]( Cx*R*cos t + R^2*cos^2 t + Cy*R*sin t + R^2*sin^2 t )dt`

`Integral[t=t0..t1]( Cx*R*cos t + Cy*R*sin t + R^2*sin^2 t + R^2*cos^2 t )dt`

`Integral[t=t0..t1]( Cx*R*cos t + Cy*R*sin t + R^2 )dt`

`Integral[t=t0..t1]( Cx*R*cos t + Cy*R*sin t )dt + R^2*(t1-t0)`

`Integral[t=t0..t1]( Cx*R*d(sin t) - Cy*R*d(cos t) ) + R^2*(t1-t0)`

`Cx*R*(sin t1-sin t0) - Cy*R*(cos t1-cos t0) ) + R^2*(t1-t0)`

`Cx*(y1-y0) - Cy*(x1-x0) ) + R^2*(t1-t0)`