# Find overlapped area between a circle and a group of polygons

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry, polygon, area

I found some solutions to find the intersection between the circle and 1 triangle.

I am searching for a solution to find a more general solution, to find the area of the circle overlapped by the polygons present in the plan.

No 2 polygons intersect each other nor self-intersect.

A circle can be intersected (overlapped) by multiple polygons.

I would appreciate a C# solution.

Comment: Why am i down voted?

Comment: probably because this is what most would consider a poor example of how to ask a question.. meaning.. what have you done and or tried on your own.. also how come you can just do a google search on the following 
`Find the area of the circle overlapped by the polygons` also looks a lot like `HomeWork`

Comment: I finished university sometime ago, this is not a homework. I googled for a solution by only found solutions for collision detection, and almost none for areas.

Comment: try this if not sounds like you will have to go back to revisiting calculus or Trig http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879535/what-algorithm-use-to-find-the-intersection-area-between-polygon-and-circle

Comment: That was helpful, now I know where to start, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Triangulate your polygons.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation)
2. For each triangle i, compute the intersection area of your circle and triangle i. Call it A[i].
   (You said you know how to do this part.)
3. The area of the intersection between your circle and your polygons is sum(A[i] for all triangles i).